# PowerBI Desktop is not supporting 'Annotation' Schema element from OData Feed

Tags: powerbi, odata, powerbi-desktop

In PowerBI Desktop, I'm trying to connect to my OData feed which returns Entity Properties with Annotation that defines the property display name ([like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/analytics-metadata?view=azure-devops#entitytypes)). But, PowerBI is not accepting the response. Instead it throws this error

> DataSource.Error: OData: The feed's metadata document appears to be
> invalid. Error: The metadata document could not be read from the
> message content.
>
> UnexpectedXmlElement: The schema element 'Annotation' was not expected
> in the given context

Is there anything to do with Version? I even tried with **ODataVersion=4.0** in Power query Advanced editor, no luck. What am I missing?

I appreciate any help in advance

Comment: Does [this](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2020/07/26/returning-annotations-from-odata-sources-in-power-bi-power-query/) help?

Comment: I think, that post is talking about custom values. What I am looking for is, custom labels for Entity Properties. I have a module with data (key => value pair). In PowerBI, I want to show 'field labels' instead of 'field names'. But I don't like sending field label as property name as label can have special characters. In PowerBI, we can rename the columns, but I am looking for a way if PowerBI auto detects the label and display that instead of names.